# basic but EXTREMELY SLOW

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I just wanted to inspect every character in a document, but this takes over the 6 minutes limit time, for a 40000 character document. I'm guessing I should store the data and then access it from there, but how is that practice called?

```
function myFunction() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var text = body.getText();
  var editText = body.editAsText();


  for (var i = 0 ; i < text.length; i++){
    Logger.log(text[i]); 
    Logger.log(editText.getAttributes(i));
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the characters? Like this you are doing 80k calls to Logger which will obviously be slow. shall it really all be logged as single chars?

Comment: I will need my script to consider every single character, in order to define patterns, in order to correct specific errors and/or attributes. Is Logging heavier than doing any other operation?

Comment: yes but in what way do you want to inspect them, a call to logger done 80k times will be slow since it's an IO operation (which for this purpose includes API calls etc.), if you do in memory stuff you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [batch operations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices) which is part of the [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices) when programming in Google Apps Script. An optimized code has been included in the guide.

You can write scripts to take maximum advantage of the built-in caching, by minimizing the number of reads and writes. Alternating read and write commands is slow. To speed up a script, read all data into an array with one command, perform any operations on the data in the array, and write the data out with one command.